# Excel sheet is not genearting in IIS.but it working fine in local machine in asp.net. I have done all setings in Domconfig files

Tags: c#, asp.net

Excel sheet is not generating in IIS.but its working fine in local system.
I have done all settings in DOMCONFIG file. but still its not working

Comment: Do you have any error message? We can't help you if you won't give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the mime type settings in IIS? .xlsx or xls extension should be available.